# Compare and Merge JSON files using PHP (CouchDB)

Tags: php, python, json, couchdb

I have a [JSON](http://json.org/) document on the [couchdb database](http://couchdb.apache.org/) and another document generated on my local computer. I want to compare both documents and update the existing document on couchdb with the differences of the local document. I have done some research and heard of [php_jsonpath](https://github.com/raphaelstolt/php-jsonpatch)
meanwhile i found a sample implementation python rather than php which is :

```
import json
import couchdb    # https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CouchDB
import jsonpatch  # https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpatch

server = couchdb.Server()
db = server['mydb']
doc_a = db['some-doc-id']
doc_b = json.load(open('doc.json', 'rb'))
patch = jsonpatch.make_patch(doc_a, doc_b)
patch.apply(doc_a)
db.save(doc_a)
```

I was wondering if someone could help me with the php equivalent of this or rather another way of implementing this with php.Thanks.

Comment: Clarify "difference".  Examples of the files and, what should happen to the couchdb version would be helpful. With your current description, it could be taken to mean that the coucdb document should simply be overwritten each time by the local version.

Comment: @gview it should indeed overwrite but i need to be able to spot the differences so that i could make certain decisions if i want to overwrite or not.

Comment: Well at least in php you can use json_decode($jsonstr, true) and turn your json into an array.  From there, you have all of php's array functions -- things like array_diff and array_diff_assoc may help you do the job.